# Paste name of column to other columns in R?

Tags: r, excel

I have recently received an output from the online survey (ESRI Survey123), storing the each recored attribte as a new column of teh table. The survey reports characteristics of single trees located on study site: e.g. beech1, beech2, etc. For each beech, several attributes are recorded such as height, shape, etc.

This is how the output table looks like in Excel. ID simply represent the site number:

[image]

Now I wonder, how can I read those data into R to make sure that columns 1:3 belong to beech1, columns 4:6 represent beech2, etc.? I am looking for something that would paste the `beech1` into names of the following columns: `beech1.height`, `beech1.shape`. But I am not sure how to do it?

[image]

Comment: The "ID" column seems useless. I would expect you to have your data set in separate rows (row 1 would be "Beech1, 1, 10, oval", row 2 would be "Beech2, 3, 11, rect" and so forth). Why would you input all the data in separate columns and ignore rows?

Comment: Hi @cybernetic.nomad the ID represent just a sample plot,on which several trees can growth. The output format is in the format of the survey recording style.